# Print NV image ESC/POS

Tags: c#, escpos

I am very new in ESC POS command. I have uploaded images to printer memory. I am able to print required image with utility comes with printer. I want to print image from my application. I don't know really how to print it using C#. I am using below code to print but it is not printing anything. Can you please guide me how to print image using C#.

```
public void PrintImage()
{

    const string FS = "\u001C";
    string command = FS + "p11";
    WriteLine(command);

}

public void WriteLine(string text)
{
    WriteToBuffer(text);
    _writeByte(10);
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(WriteLineSleepTimeMs);
}
private void _writeByte(byte valueToWrite)
{
    byte[] tempArray = {valueToWrite};
    _serialPort.Write(tempArray,0,1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically, ESC/POS prints with byte[] instead of string(Unicode).
Actually, WriteToBuffer() seems to send the character string and command of the print request, but if there is no source for this part, an accurate answer cannot be made.

---

The command you are going to use is this one, which prints the NV image defined by the "FS q" command.
This is a deprecated(non-recommended?/obsolete?) mode in the included utility and should not be used.

[FS p [obsolete command]](https://reference.epson-biz.com/modules/ref_escpos/index.php?content_id=89) : Print NV bit image
[FS q [obsolete command]](https://reference.epson-biz.com/modules/ref_escpos/index.php?content_id=89) : Define NV bit image

However, if you really want to use the "FS p" command, the byte data sent to the printer will be:

```
byte[] NVimageCmd = { 0x1c, 0x70, 0x01, 0x31 };
```

The NV image number that should be specified is the numeric value 1 (0x01), not the character '1'.

---

Another command is currently recommended for use, as described below in the command description above.

> [Recommended Functions]
>   This function is supported only by some printer models and may not be supported by future models. It is recommended that NV graphics function ([GS ( L / GS 8 L](https://reference.epson-biz.com/modules/ref_escpos/index.php?content_id=95#gs_lparen_cl): [GS ( L <Function 51>](https://reference.epson-biz.com/modules/ref_escpos/index.php?content_id=102#gs_lparen_cl_fn51) and [GS ( L <Function 64>](https://reference.epson-biz.com/modules/ref_escpos/index.php?content_id=103#gs_lparen_cl_fn64) – [GS ( L <Function 69>](https://reference.epson-biz.com/modules/ref_escpos/index.php?content_id=107#gs_lparen_cl_fn69)) be used because they offer the following additional features:

Use the following command to print the NV image registered with the supplied utility.
kc1 and kc2 are the key codes specified when registering.

[GS ( L <Function 69>](https://reference.epson-biz.com/modules/ref_escpos/index.php?content_id=107#gs_lparen_cl_fn69) : Print the specified NV graphics data.

By the way, if the printer and utility are in Advanced Printer Driver mode, send the control font according to the explanation of that mode.